# My smart smart contract won't send to multiple addresses

Tags: solidity, contract-development, contract-deployment, contract-invocation, contract-debugging

I have experienced some difficulties in getting deployed multisend/airdrop smart contract to distribute tokens to multiple addresses by interacting with the main contract. Each time it failed.

Kindly Note:
**The smart contract which initially owns the tokens does not have the multisend function. Please find the code it here.** (https://ropsten.etherscan.io/address/0x259059f137cb9b8f60ae27bd199d97abb69e539b)

**I deployed a multisend ownable contract from the same owner who deployed the one above here** (https://ropsten.etherscan.io/address/0xb608a6c42afe7d9f5bcdda2276e351ec65dfa93f). **Normally this new contract should seamlessly interact with the former to send out tokens, but each time I did, the transaction failed with an error** (https://ropsten.etherscan.io/tx/0xf959ddc55c2e551b82a8448ad267601dfddc4785e1236bbc52f46b2389b500f1) (please find attached pic).

[image: failed tx]

**Before attempting to send tokens with multisend contract, I sent the required tokens from the parent smart contract to the multisend contract.**

Kindly I have to seek for advice from experts here.
Help review my code and correct me where necessary. I would be super grateful. Thank you.

Comment: Oh Gosh, no one to help me?

Comment: Bumped for an answer. I really need an answer do contine my work.

Comment: That transaction failed for multiple reasons, but the question was asked in July.